# how to extract whole row using .loc or .iloc function if index is non-integer value

Tags: python, pandas

Here is the output of my code but now I want to extract the values of Check_In and Check_Out in variables so that I can perform own these values any suggestions on how to extract the values?

```
ID    Name        Check_In           Check_Out           
1     Zainab      7 am       5 pm
2   Abdullah      8 am       5 pm
3     Hassan      9 am       6 pm
4    Javeria     11 am       9 pm
5     Tayyab      7 am       5 pm
6     Fatima     11 am       9 pm
```

This is my code below:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv("Book1.csv")
c = df.set_index('ID')
print(c)
f = int(input('Give ID number:' ))
t = (pd.DataFrame((c.loc[f])))
print(t)
```

This is the prompt:

```
Give ID number:2
>> 2

Name       Abdullah
Check_In        8am
Check_Out       5pm
```

Comment: Please modify your post to make results into code, what you have tried, and desired results

Comment: please provide the full dataframes including headers, but it looks like you want a simple Series slicing…

Comment: You need to post your code. See [mre] and [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341).

Comment: Please modify your post to include sample output. It is not clear whether you want a list which contains values like `[Check_in, Check_out]` or you want two variables `Check_In`, `Check_Out` separately.

Comment: @Zainab Tahir, if you have found your answer in one of the below, can you please click the check mark to accept it as your solution.

[what-to-do-when-i-get-answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pandas.DataFrame.values](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) after user input the choice of `ID`. Since `.values` returns a NumPy array, I had to use slice indexing. (*Scenario if user enters 2 as input*)

```py
check_in = t.loc['Check_In'].values[0] 
check_out = t.loc['Check_Out'].values[0] 
print(check_in)
print(check_out)
```

Output:

```
8:00 AM
5:00 PM
```

Comment: import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.read_csv("Book1.csv")
c=df.set_index('ID')
print(c)
f=int(input('Give ID number:' ))
t=(pd.DataFrame((c.loc[f])))
print(t)
check_in = df['Check_In'].values
check_out = df['Check_Out'].values
print(check_out)        this is my code may be you will be able to understand it more I want to extract the value of Check_In and check_out from variable t

Comment: You should note that your variable `t` is **pandas.core.frame.DataFrame** type. So it is still DataFrame. If you run `print(t.values)` in your notebook, you will see it returns a list something like [['Hassan'],  ['9:00 AM'], ['6:00 PM']]. Then you can do slicing `t.values[1:3]`. Just for the sake of efficiency, I ask you to put an image of what the output should look like in your original post. Still, it is not clear what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This will set your index to "Name" as well as select an index that is a string instead of a int

```
df.set_index('Name', inplace = True)
df.loc[['Zainab']].squeeze()
```

You can remove the .squeeze() if you simply want to have a df of the results.

Answer (score 0):

IUUC, you can use `Series.loc`

```py
c = df.set_index('ID')
f = 2
t = c.loc[f]
check_in = t.loc['Check_In']
check_out = t.loc['Check_Out']

# without `t`
check_in = c.loc[f, 'Check_In']
```

```
print(check_in)
8 am

print(check_out)
5pm
```

Or you can use

```py
check_ins = df.loc[df['ID'].eq(f), 'Check_In'].tolist()
```

```
print(check_ins)

['8 am']
```